# invoice has 1 line item, but showing full price

Tags: civicontribute, invoice

I have setup a webform to sell tickets to events. A user can add multiple ticks for multiple users. When printing/emailing the invoice only 1 ticket appears. When viewing in the Civi dashboard the correct amount of tickets appear. I have added screen captures to show in more detail. Has anyone else experienced the same issue? Cheers.

[image]
[image]

Comment: This extension fixed the issue of line items not showing up on the invoice https://github.com/fuzionnz/nz.co.fuzion.webformparticipants